# using APNS function to navigate to desired content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, apple-push-notifications

I am wondering, how to use APNS function to navigate to desired content, like strait times apps, which it only push the title of the news to the user(I've managed to do this part), but when the user click view, it'll directly fire the apps and go directly to the content which title being shown as the alert in push. I only managed to go to the main page of my apps.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom data in the payload, for example the id of the news to show.

**Example** :

```
 {
    "aps":
        {"alert":"test",
        "badge":1,
        "sound":"default"
        },
    "Value1":info,
    "Value2":3,
      "myDict":
       {
         "key1":"val1",
         "key2":val2
       }
    }
```

**And to access in the code** :

```
- (void)receivedRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSDictionnary *myDict = [userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"aps.myDict"];

}
```